# Slow PHP script - automatic debug and diagnosis?

Tags: php, optimization, scripting

How can I find out whether a PHP script goes bad and runs really slow when ran by hundreds of users every second, and better yet, is there any tool that could tell me approximately which part of the code slows me down?
...

I don't wish to post the code here (mainly because this question refers to something else and because it's a waste of space) and preferably never post it anywhere because it's actually a mess!... a mess that I understand and yes, i coded it, but still a mess which would insult anyone trying to comprehend it... so if you have any creative ideas, please let me know!

Cheers!

( thank you already for your incoming answers! )

Comment: Does your code execute database query/ies?

Comment: start a timmer at the top, output how much time has passed at strategic points. find the slowest, and fix

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Enable [XDebug profiling](http://xdebug.org/), and send the resulting files through [WinCacheGrind](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wincachegrind/) (Windows) or [KCacheGrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html) (Linux).

This will allow you to see a breakdown of which functions get called most, and where the time is spent. Learning to use XDebug is a must for any serious PHP developer.

Here is a [seemingly good tutorial on getting started with XDebug profiling](https://devzone.zend.com/1139/profiling-php-applications-with-xdebug/).

Comment: I will try to use it... as i can see, it's a bit of a "big manual needed" kind of program, so i'll be learning it after next week's exams... thanks for the tutorial anyway!

Answer (score 3):

You will need two tools

- a profiler (Google it)

i use this one at work :

http://www.nusphere.com/products/php_profiler.htm (commercial)

- a load tester

check this site for more info :

http://performance-testing.org/content/performance-testing-tools

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend to use a PHP profiler. [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) which is both PHP debugger and profiler can help a lot. There are also other debuggers, e.g. Zend Debugger.

To analyze profiling results you could also need a special tool. I used [WinCacheGrind](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wincachegrind/) in Windows and [KCachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html) in Linux.

Profiling report shows tons of useful information e.g. which lines of the source code were called how many times and which functions took the most of the execution time.