# PHP Mailer taking over 30 seconds to send a welcome email

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

So I am using the PHPMailer library in PHP to send a welcome email when ever my users registered, and it takes so long to do this.

It takes around 30 - 50 seconds to actually load the home page, after clicking submit on the registration. It basically puts the page in a reloading state for over 30 seconds.

The code I use is below...

```
if ($config['user']['welcome_email_enabled'])
    $autoLoader->getLibrary('mail')->sendWelcomeEmail($email, $username);
```

And my mail library is here.

```
<?php
/**
 * MangoCMS, content management system.
 *
 * @info         Handles the mail functions.
 * @author       Liam Digital <liamatzubbo@outlook.com>
 * @version      1.0 BETA
 * @package      MangoCMS_Master
 *
 */

defined("CAN_VIEW") or die('You do not have permission to view this file.');

class mangoMail {
    private $phpMailer;

    public function assignMailer($phpMailer) {
        $this->phpMailer = $phpMailer;
    }

    public function setupMail($username, $password, $eHost) {
        if ($this->phpMailer == null)
            return;

        $this->phpMailer->isSMTP();
        $this->phpMailer->Host = $eHost;
        $this->phpMailer->SMTPAuth = true;
        $this->phpMailer->Username = $username;
        $this->phpMailer->Password = $password;
        $this->phpMailer->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $this->phpMailer->Port = 587;
    }

    public function sendMail() {
        if ($this->phpMailer == null)
            return;

        if (!$this->phpMailer->send()) {
            echo 'Message could not be sent.';
            echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $this->phpMailer->ErrorInfo;
            exit();
        }
        else {
            echo 'Email has been sent.';
        }
    }

    public function setFrom($from, $fromTitle) {
        $this->phpMailer->setFrom($from, $fromTitle);
    }

    public function addAddress($address) {
        $this->phpMailer->addAddress($address);
    }

    public function setSubject($subject) {
        $this->phpMailer->Subject = $subject;
    }

    public function setBody($body) {
        $this->phpMailer->Body = $body;
    }

    public function setAltBody($altBody) {
        $this->phpMailer->AltBody = $altBody;
    }

    public function setHTML($html) {
        $this->phpMailer->isHTML($html);
    }

    public function addReply($email, $name = '') {
        $this->phpMailer->addReplyTo($email, $name);
    }

    public function sendWelcomeEmail($email, $username) {
        global $config;
        $mailer = $this->phpMailer;
        $mailer->setFrom($config['website']['email'], $config['website']['owner']);
        $mailer->addAddress($email, $username);
        $mailer->addReplyTo($config['website']['email'], 'Reply Here');
        $mailer->isHTML(true);
        $mailer->Subject = 'Welcome to ' . $config['website']['name'] . ' (' . $config['website']['link'] . ')';
        $mailer->Body = '<div style="background-color:#1a8cff;padding:24px;color:#fff;border-radius:3px;">
        <h2>Welcome to Zubbo ' . $username . '!</h2>Thank you for joining the Zubbo community, we offer spectacular events, opportunities, and entertainment.<br><br>When you join Zubbo you will recieve <b>250,000 credits</b>, <b>100,000 duckets</b>, and <b>5 diamonds</b>. One way to earn more is by being online and active, the more you are active the more you will earn, other ways are competitions, events, and games :)<br><br>We strive to keep the community safe and secure, so if you have any questions or concerns or have found a bug please reply to this email or contact us using in-game support.<br><br>Thank you for joining Zubbo Hotel!<br>- Zubbo Staff Team
        </div>';
        $mailer->AltBody = 'Here is a alt body...';
        if (!$mailer->send()) {
            exit('FAILED TO SEND WELCOME EMAIL!! ' . $mailer->ErrorInfo);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

So I call these to start with, then the sendWelcomeEmail() when I want to actually send the email.

$mailer->assignMailer(new PHPMailer());

and

```
$mailer->setupMail(
    "********@gmail.com",
    "**************",
    "smtp.gmail.com");
```

Why is it taking so long? Should it be taking this long..

Comment: you should benchmark to find out where the load time is, all phpmailer does is send the message to the mailserver (it does not wait after that for the message to actually be sent), its unlikely to be the problem.

Comment: Have you tried doing a test independent of a lot of rendering and just trigger the email function?

Comment: Any reason to use gmail, vs your hosts mail sever? that's always gong to be slower.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477396/slow-php-script-automatic-debug-and-diagnosis

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPMailer using Gmail SMTP slow when sending emails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20068484/phpmailer-using-gmail-smtp-slow-when-sending-emails)

Comment: Just to notify you all, it works super fast on localhost, but on a server it doesnt.. also I am pretty sure the latency is in the sendEmail() function because when I remove that it goes super fast (1-2 seconds)

Answer (score 1):

Remote SMTP is not really a good thing to use during page submissions - it's often very slow (sometimes deliberately, for greetdelay checks), as you're seeing. The way around it is to always submit to a local (fast) mail server and let it deal with the waiting around, and also handle things like deferred delivery which you can't handle from PHPMailer. You also need to deal with bounces correctly when going that route as you won't get immediate feedback.

That you can often get away with direct delivery doesn't mean it's a reliable approach.

To see what part of the SMTP conversation is taking a long time, set `$mailer->SMTPDebug = 2;` and watch the output (though don't do that on your live site!).

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if PHPMailer is compulsory for you or not, but if it's not I am recommanding [SwiftMailer](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/tree/5.x/lib) .

as per my personal Experience It's Really fast and reliable.

Thanks.

```
include_once "inc/swift_required.php";

$subject = 'Hello from Jeet Patel, PHP!'; //this will Subject
$from = array('jeet@mydomain.com' =>'mydomain.com'); //you can use variable

$text = "This is TEXT PART";
$html = "<em>This IS <strong>HTML</strong></em>";

$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('abc.xyz.com', 465, 'ssl');
$transport->setUsername('MYUSERNAME@MYDOMAIN.COM');
$transport->setPassword('*********');
$swift = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);



    $to = array($row['email']  => $row['cname']);
    $message = new Swift_Message($subject);
    $message->setFrom($from);
    $message->setBody($html, 'text/html');
    $message->setTo($to);
    $message->addPart($text, 'text/plain');

    if ($swift->send($message, $failures))
    {
        echo "Send successfulllyy";
    } else {
        print_r($failures);

    }
```